# Python multiprocessing on ipykernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I want to make some parallel CPU-bound computations in Python, I was writing my code on a notebook running on my machine with ipykernel.

I reduced my problem to the following simple replicable code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pprint import pprint

def square(num):
    return num ** 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = list(range(20))
    with Pool() as pool:
        res = pool.map(square, lst)
    pprint(res)
```

This works fine when I run it as a script, now if I just copy paste it into a notebook.ipynb and try to run it, it keeps running way longer than it should giving some obscure warnings as follows:

```
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

Why is my code not running on a notebook and how can I solve this?

I also tried removing `if __name__ == '__main__'` in the notebook to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the frozen modules ?

```py
python -Xfrozen_modules=off -m <run-script>
```

Comment: I usually run .ipynb from vs code, running every chunck of code separately clicking, how can I do that? This seems a way to run from terminal as a script